# iCloud file copies fail on 1 of 4 computers with the same AppleID

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I have a MacBook Air (circa 2014) running a fresh copy of Big Sur and noticed that iCloud file copies are failing.

The problem does not occur on 3 other computers using the same AppleID: a 2010 Pro running High Sierra, a 2013 iMac running Catalina, and a 2019 iMac running Sonoma.

If I log into iCloud on the Air using a different AppleID, iCloud works correctly. So it appears that the combination of the offending AppleID and the Air is the combination that fails since the AppleID in question functions correctly on 3 other computers.

Does Apple maintain a table of MAC addresses+AppleID for each AppleID or some other unique identifier for a computer+AppleID that could be corrupt somewhere is Apple's iCloud universe?

Any thoughts out there?

Comment: Are the other Macs logged in to the same Apple ID concurrently when this happens, or does the Big Sur Mac never connect, no matter which other Macs are logged in?

Comment: All computers are concurrently logged in. The Big Sur Mac is able to do all iCloud operations except for file transfers/synchronizations.